# How to delete entities at the bottom of a cascade -> non-cascade deletion chain in EF?

Tags: c#, sql, entity-framework

Sorry for the entirely unhelpful title... I couldn't put this problem into any better words.

I have the following entities, each of which are identified by an `Id` attribute:

- Chassis
- Slots
- Cards

As I'm using POCO, the entities are nothing ground breaking. For instance, the `Chassis` class is defined like so:

```
public class Chassis
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    // Other properties omitted for brevity.

    public ICollection<Slot> Slots { get; set; }

    public Chassis() 
    {
        Slots = new Collection<Slot>();
    }
}
```

The relationships are as follows:

- A chassis has many slots (`CASCADE`).
- A card has many slots, as a card can be a multi-slot card (`SET NULL`).
- A slot must belong to a `Chassis` (`pubic int ChassisId { get; set; }`)
- A slot does not have to have a `Card` (`public int? CardId { get; set; }`).

So, when deleting a chassis, all slots are deleted. **Fine**. However, I'd also like to delete all of the cards that were installed in those slots. **Not fine**. I'm trying to hook some code into an `OnSavingChanges` event (which I fire just before `SaveChanges()`), such that when a chassis is marked deleted, I delete the cards for it as well.

First, I tried:

```
OnSavingChanges += (x, y) =>
{
    var ctx = x as DbContext;
    var chassis = ctx.ChangeTracker.Entries<Chassis>().Where(e => e.State == EntityState.Deleted);

    // Delete all cards on a deleted chassis.
    foreach (var c in chassis)
    {
        // Cannot just do c.Slots, as EF seems to empty the nav. property now the
        // chassis is deleted.
        var slots = ctx.Slots.Where(s => s.ChassisId == c.Entity.Id).ToList();

        foreach (var s in slots)
        {
            if (s.Card != null)
            {
                ctx.Cards.Remove(s.Card);
            }
        }
    }
};
```

... but this throws the exception:

> An exception of type 'System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DbUpdateException' occurred in EntityFramework.dll but was not handled in user code
>
> Additional information: Unable to insert or update an entity because the principal end of the 'Chassis_Slots' relationship is deleted.

I then tried to add `ctx.Detach(s);` within my inner `foreach` loop, to stop EF trying to save the already-deleted-via-cascade Slots entity:

```
foreach (var s in slots)
{
    if (s.Card != null)
    {
        ctx.Cards.Remove(s.Card);
    }

    // Otherwise EF attempts to save the slot, which results in a exception saying the principle
    // end of the relatioship Chassis_Slots has already been deleted.
    ctx.Detach(s);
}
```

... however EF then cries with the following exception:

> Additional information: The DELETE statement conflicted with the REFERENCE constraint "FK_dbo.Slots_dbo.Cards_CardId". The conflict occurred in database "...", table "dbo.Slots", column 'CardId'.
>
> The statement has been terminated.

... which kinda leaves me between a rock and a hard place, and completely out of ideas.

**Can anyone suggest a more successful way/ approach to do this?**

Comment: Could you also post the three models?

Comment: @YuliamChandra: they're all quite boring... I'm using POCO. I've added a sample for `Chassis`. `Slot` and `Cards` are literally defined the same.

Comment: I can't replicate your issue, maybe we have different models, are [these models](https://dotnetfiddle.net/2sCV11) similar with yours?

Comment: @YuliamChandra: Yes. Which of my code samples are you using? Are you using a CASCADE relationship on the Chassis -> Slot relation, and NULL on the Slot -> Card? So when you delete a chassis, the slots **and cards** get deleted for it?

Comment: yes, on delete cascade on chassis, what do you mean by `null on the slot -> card`. is it optional CardId `public int? CardId`? or on delete set null which I have to edit manually on the database constraint?

Comment: @YuliamChandra: Optional CardId. Humm. I'll try recreate a SSCCE soon... Unfortunately I'm just about to walk out the door, but I'll update later.

Comment: @Isaac You say that cards can belong to multiple slots but once a single slot is deleted you try to delete the cards it held?  Are you sure you want to do that?  What if non deleted slots reference that card?  I believe that is what the last error message is saying.

Comment: @Vulcronos: A card will only ever belong to slots which are part of the same chassis. Therefore, when I delete a chassis (and all of it's slots) I know that all cards that *were* installed in those slots are now orphans. It's those that I want to ensure are deleted.

Answer (score 4):

Here is the sequence.

- When `Chassis` is deleted, all `Slots` will also be deleted because of the delete cascade mechanism. Simple right?
- Then you intercept the saving changes, you want to also delete `Card` manually on <s>the same transaction</s> single `SaveChanges`, which I'm not sure how EF will generate the sql query even though the cards deletion syntax is added later, but when I checked it using profiler, it deleted cards first (should be chassis first).
- What happens is, the `Unchanged Slot` (that will be automatically deleted by `delete cascade`) changes into `Modified Slot`.
- Why? Because when you also delete `Card`, the corresponding `Slot's CardId` has to be set as null.
- Now the final result is `Slot` becomes modified, but `Chassis` has been deleted.

To fix the problem, you need to introduce new <s>transaction /</s> context.

```
public override int SaveChanges()
{
    var deletedCardIds = new List<int>();
    var chassises = ChangeTracker.Entries<Chassis>().Where(e => e.State == EntityState.Deleted);
    foreach (var chassis in chassises)
    {
        var slots = Slots.Where(s => s.ChassisId == chassis.Entity.Id).ToArray();
        foreach (var slot in slots)
        {
            if (slot.CardId.HasValue && !deletedCardIds.Contains(slot.CardId.Value))
            {
                deletedCardIds.Add(slot.CardId.Value);
            }
        }
    }

    // Commits original transaction.
    var originalRowsAffected = base.SaveChanges();

    int additionalRowsAffected = 0;
    if (deletedCardIds.Count > 0)
    {
        // Opens new transaction.
        using (var newContext = new AppContext())
        {
            foreach (var cardId in deletedCardIds)
            {
                var deletedCard = newContext.Cards.Find(cardId);
                if (deletedCard != null)
                {
                    newContext.Cards.Remove(deletedCard);
                }
            }

            // Commits new transaction.
            additionalRowsAffected = newContext.SaveChanges();
        }
    }

    return originalRowsAffected + additionalRowsAffected;
}
```

## PS

- You have two separated transactions, it might cause unexpected behavior ([atomicity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atomicity_%28database_systems%29) is not guaranteed).
- You might want to redesign the database for ideal solution.

## UPDATE

Today I just realized that we can just simply use a [TransactionScope](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.transactions.transactionscope%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to [commit several operations in a single transaction](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/dn456843.aspx). Just like doing this code in database.

```
begin tran
delete from dbo.Chassis
delete from dbo.Cards
commit tran
```

If you use EF6 onwards, you can just use [Database.BeginTransaction](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entity.database.begintransaction%28v=vs.113%29.aspx) otherwise use `TransactionScope`.

```
public override int SaveChanges()
{
    var deletedCardIds = new List<int>();
    var chassises = ChangeTracker.Entries<Chassis>().Where(e => e.State == EntityState.Deleted);
    foreach (var chassis in chassises)
    {
        var cardIds = Slots.Where(s => s.ChassisId == chassis.Entity.Id)
            .Where(s => s.CardId.HasValue)
            .Select(s => s.CardId.Value)
            .ToArray();
        deletedCardIds.AddRange(cardIds);
    }

    int originalRowsAffected;
    int additionalRowsAffected;
    using (var transaction = new TransactionScope())
    {
        originalRowsAffected = base.SaveChanges();

        deletedCardIds.Distinct().ToList()
            .ForEach(id => Entry(new Card { Id = id }).State = EntityState.Deleted);
        additionalRowsAffected = base.SaveChanges();

        transaction.Complete();
    }

    return originalRowsAffected + additionalRowsAffected;
}
```

By introducing transaction at above updated code, both `SaveChanges` either all occur, or nothing occurs, atomicity is guaranteed now.

Comment: Humm. Thanks for looking into this in so much detail. I was really hoping to avoid loosing atomicity here, as these relationships are the centre-part of my application and wholly integral. How would you propose redesigning the database? This was something I looked into, but I was sure I'd chosen the most adequate model. What did you have to change from being unable-to-recreate my problem to being able to reproduce it? Ideally I can just get rid of this problem in the first place (i.e. do the opposite of what you changed!).

Comment: @Isaac, to be able to reproduce I changed the required Card into optional Card on Slot. Yup do the opposite (just like I did first time) would be ideal.

Comment: Ah, thanks; I'll update the question to include that detail. Unfortunately I can't have a non-optional relationship, as I have `Slots` which are empty. I'll wait to see if I can get an atomic answer posted, but won't forget to accept this if not! Thanks for your help so far!

Answer (score 2):

There are a few elements about your current solution that is making the cascading delete troublesome.

1. The `Card` entity is self-referential. I.e. a card can either be a leaf-level card (with no child cards), or a branch-level card which aggregates child cards. From a domain perspective, I imagine that either a card has no children or exactly one set of children. I will use this assumed domain knowledge as part of my solution. Given free reign, I would remodel this as two entities: `Card` and `CardWithChildren` and make this explicit.
2. Without knowing more about your domain, it appears that the `Slot` entity is purely an object orientated device to allow `Card` entities to belong to either a `Chassis` or another `Card`. However, I would look at the relationship the other way around to how stated in the question. Rather than a slot can belong to a chassis or a card, I would model this as a card belongs to a slot, and then express the relationship polymorphically on the card. This can then be further reduced to just saying that a card is owned by either a chassis or a further card.

Here's an example that takes into consideration the above. It has the following features:

1. To allow the relationship between cards and containing chassis and parent cards, I have modelled the chassis and card types as extending a base type called `CardContainer` that aggregates cards through a card collection.
2. The `CardContainer` entity model will then be expressed as a **TPT** (table per type) strategy by Entity Framework, leading to three tables: `CardContainers`, `Cards` and `Chassis`. I.e. *I have made a slight change to your data model to abstract the collection aspects of cards and chassis into a separate table*. The `Card` and `Chassis` entities then have a shared primary key back to their respective `CardContainer` entity.
3. The self-referential nature of the Cards table will remain. Theoretically this means that we can have an infinite depth of card-->card relationships. However, to allow the Entity Framework cascading delete to work with the TPT strategy, we need to explicitly tell Entity Framework about the maximum depth when retrieving cards. This is done by **Including** the correct depth of cards as part of the retrieval of a chassis entity.

This approach requires a single call to `SaveChanges` on a single `Context` and is hence **atomic**.

**NOTE**: This solution doesn't contain a `Slot` entity for the reasons above as well as to keep the code sample small(ish). However, this solution can easily be extended to add it back by making `Card` and `Chassis` extend a `SlotCollection`, which in turn aggregates `Slot` entities which hold a single `Card` entity. The fundamental approach remains the same.

**Entity Framework Code First POCO's**

```
public abstract class CardContainer
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Card> Cards { get; set; }

    protected CardContainer()
    {
        Cards = new List<Card>();
    }
}

public class Chassis : CardContainer
{             
}

public class Card : CardContainer
{
    public CardContainer Container { get; set; }
    public int ContainerId { get; set; }
}
```

**POCO Configurations**

```
public class CardContainerConfiguration : EntityTypeConfiguration<CardContainer>
{
    public CardContainerConfiguration()
    {
        ToTable("CardContainers");
        HasKey(k => k.Id);
        Property(p => p.Id).HasDatabaseGeneratedOption(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity);   
        HasMany(f => f.Cards)
            .WithRequired(p => p.Container)
            .HasForeignKey(p => p.ContainerId)
            .WillCascadeOnDelete(true);
    }
}

public class ChassisConfiguration : EntityTypeConfiguration<Chassis>
{
    public ChassisConfiguration()
    {
        ToTable("Chassis");
    }
}

public class CardConfiguration : EntityTypeConfiguration<Card>
{
    public CardConfiguration()
    {
        ToTable("Cards");
        HasRequired(x => x.Container).WithMany(x => x.Cards).HasForeignKey(x => x.ContainerId);            
    }
}
```

**Example Context**

```
public class EfContext : DbContext
{              
    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {           
        modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(new CardContainerConfiguration());
        modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(new ChassisConfiguration());
        modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(new CardConfiguration());           

        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
    }
}
```

**Example usage**

```
public void CanCascadeDeleteCards()
{
    using (var context = new EfContext())
    {
        // We have to tell Entity Framework of the maximum depth of the 
        // card-->card relationship using the Include method
        var chassis = context.CardContainers.OfType<Chassis>()
            .Include(x => x.Cards.Select(y => y.Cards))
            .First();
        context.CardContainers.Remove(chassis);             
        context.SaveChanges();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Why are you deleting a chassis and then only deleting the cards in an extra event?  I believe that is causing all of your problems.  In my projects, whenever I want to delete both parent and children without an explict cascade relationship in the database, I always start with the children and then delete the parents without any problem.

In your code to delete a chassis, get all the slots and iterate through them and remov all your cards, just like you do currently in the event.  If you mark the cards as deleted before you delete the chassis or slots, then when you delete the cards it won't mark the slots as modified.  That should prevent your error and let you delete everything in one transaction.

It is also far cleaner and easier to read to mark all entites as deleted in one spot.  Right now, it is very easy for anyone reading your chassis delete to not realize that also deletes any cards associated with it.